# Spell Correction using TextBlob, autocorrect

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, textblob, autocorrect

I had been trying to implement a function that would correct spellings in multiple documents. I tried two methods viz `TextBlob` and `autocorrect`.

**Using TextBlob**

```
def spell_correct(word_list):
    try:
        corrected = []
        for word in word_list:
            w = Word(word)
            corrected.append(w.correct())
        return corrected
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return None
```

**Using autocorrect**

```
def spell_correct(word_list):
     try:
         corrected = []
         for word in word_list:
             corrected.append(spell(word))
         return corrected
     except UnicodeDecodeError:
         return None
```

Both of them work quite well on single list of words provided as input. However, when I work with multiple documents in a pandas `DataFrame` of 13k rows, it is taking so much time that I usually `KeyboardInterrupt`. Am I impatient or is there a faster method to spell correct?

**Update**
This is how I apply these functions on multiple documents in a pandas `DataFrame`,

```
df['corrected_words'] = df.words.apply(lambda x: spell_correct(x))
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions?

Comment: I apply it on each entry this way,
`df['corrected_words'] = df.words.apply(lambda x: spell_correct(x))`

Comment: It's usually preferred if you edit your answer to answer clarification questions that require code. Can you please do that?

Comment: @ndmeiri I didn't get that. What exactly should I be doing?

Comment: A simple optimization you can apply here is convert the list of words from your document to set and correct the words and apply the same to all of the word list.

Comment: @LaBee I was just hoping that you could edit your question to include your answer to my comment. Thanks!

Comment: That is fine. On to it. @ndmeiri

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite a bit old, but I encountered a similar problem. Have you checked SymSpell of Wolf Garbe, it's a fast spelling correction that is able to pass 5000 words in 1 second (on Mac Book Pro). I guess this could help in a similar problem as you posted here. He published the whole documentation etc on https://github.com/wolfgarbe/SymSpell

Make sure to pip install it
 first

```
python -m pip install -U symspellpy
```

run it then with:

```
from symspellpy.symspellpy import SymSpell 

def main():
    # maximum edit distance per dictionary precalculation
    max_edit_distance_dictionary = 2
    prefix_length = 7
    # create object
    sym_spell = SymSpell(max_edit_distance_dictionary, prefix_length)

    # create dictionary using corpus.txt
    if not sym_spell.create_dictionary(<path/to/corpus.txt>):
        print("Corpus file not found")
        return

    for key, count in sym_spell.words.items():
        print("{} {}".format(key, count))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```